# How do i display all markers on google map even if latitude and longitude having same values?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

I have a data which is having same latitude and longitude in array of objects , but when I tried to add markers by using latitude and longitude, only some markers are showing which are not having same values. I am not getting any idea how to display all markers even if latitude and longitude have same values.

For reference I am adding stack blitz URL :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-gwxjlo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only one marker will show at a given latitude/longitude. If you want to show multiple markers close to each other I suggest you modify your duplicate lat/lng by one so that they stack near each other i.e. from 64.31586727164485 to 64.31586727164486

Comment: At first @Sakshi Thanks for your time. I tried the way which you explained by changing the latitude and longitude values which are duplicated ones, but its not working. Can u elaborate the build of the modification it means a lot

Comment: Term to search on is "spiderfy".

Answer (score 0):

I checked your sample code and I can see that the markers with the same coordinates are being generated. You can only see one marker on that coordinate because the markers are stacked to the same coordinate as they have the same scale and anchor point. If you would like to show them all at once you can change the icon properties especially the scale(1 icon is bigger than the other) or the anchor point(the `x and y` origin of the marker). Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-kfwyeu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) where I added an `anchor` in your icons and deviate it to different `y` point.

You can also use different [image icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons) so that the shapes of each icons differ and you will notice that there are multiple icons on that point.